# I can't send a parameter containing curly brackets via get method in php curl

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm working on application APIs. I'm trying to create a bot to pull data with php. In short, I need to send a parameter under the GET method, this parameter contains a json data, so I cover it with curly brackets, but when I do this, php curl does not work properly and I make a request to a url that I do not want, can you help me please?

Comment: Make sure you use `urlencode()` on the parameters.

Comment: of course:                                                                                                                      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/api/?params={"need":"help"}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');

Comment: Put code in the question, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()` to create the JSON, and `urlencode()` to encode it properly for use in a URL.

```
$param = urlencode(json_encode(['need' => 'help']));
curl_setopt($ch, CUROPT_URL, "example.com/api/?params=$param");
```